# What is the recommended way to authorize a Flattr desktop application using OAuth2?

Tags: oauth-2.0, desktop-application, flattr

I'm building a plugin for an RSS desktop client which allows users to directly flattr things (i.e. blog posts) from within the client. Since it's a Java application I use [flattr4j](http://www.shredzone.org/projects/flattr4j), which itself works fine so far.

My only remaining problem centers around the authorization workflow, which uses OAuth 2.0. Since flattr uses the authorization workflow described in [section 4.1 of the OAuth 2.0 spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-21#section-4.1), I need to adhere to the prerequisites mentioned there, i.e.

> The authorization code grant type is used to obtain both access tokens and refresh tokens and is optimized for confidential clients. As a redirection-based flow, the client must be capable of interacting with the resource owner's user-agent (typically a web browser) and capable of receiving incoming requests (via redirection) from the authorization server.

I managed to implement this workflow by

1. embedding a web browser control into my application (I could problably use the user's real web browser as well)
2. running a tiny local HTTP server which gets hit by the web browser via the OAuth callback URL mechanism in order to receive the OAuth code

Especially the last point looks error-prone to me. Since I need to register the callback URLs in advance (e.g. in my case `http://localhost:port/whatever`), I'm forced the speculate about a safe, non-used local port in order run a local HTTP server which receives the OAuth code at the end of the authorization workflow.

On the other side [the flattr4j documentation mentions a different workflow](http://www.shredzone.org/projects/flattr4j/wiki/OAuth_Procedure), which looks more appealing to me for my use case:

> "Client" based applications cannot offer a callback URL. Desktop or mobile device applications, for example, do not run a web server at all. For client based applications, Flattr will show a validation code on the website. The user will be required to enter the code in your application, in order to complete the authentication process.

And some lines further down:

> When the user accepts, a validation code is generated by Flattr. If the application was registered as "Browser" typed, the callback URL you stated will be invoked with the code and the state as parameters. For "Client" applications, the code is presented to the user instead, and he is asked to enter the code in your application manually.

This workflow might not be perfect, but much more robust for a desktop application in my opinion.

(As for the application registration: I registered my application with the platform *Desktop (Any)*. The platform seems to be more fine-grained compared to the above mentioned "Browser" vs. "Client" alternatives.)

So my questions are:

1. Is a callback-less OAuth workflow still supported by Flattr? (Was it ever supported?)
2. If so: how can I initiate this workflow?
3. If not: are my concerns valid, or is the "open web browser, initiate authorization process and receive OAuth code via locally running HTTP server" just the way to go? Are there any alternatives that I overlooked?

**UPDATE** There is another option which I'm investigating now: I set up an "OAuth landing page" which is used as the callback URL. This website's only purpose is to display the OAuth code, which then can be copied to the Desktop application by the user. Not perfect, but looks more robust to me at the moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flattr4j docs also say that a "client" authorisation is not supported by the current Flattr API. A callback-less OAuth was supported in an earlier version of the API (until April 2012), but now isn't supported any more, and it seems like it won't come back again...

There is an alternative, [which is used on Android systems](http://www.shredzone.org/projects/flattr4j/wiki/OAuth_Android). You could register an own protocol (e.g. "flattr4j://") with your operating system and pass an appropriate callback URL to Flattr. When the authentication process returns with this callback URL, your operating system would invoke your application and pass in the application key and secret. However, I think this approach is quite difficult to implement, especially when you try to find an OS independent solution.

Sadly, there is no other way I would know of.

Comment: I also tried using a custom protocol with an embedded browser, but it didn't seem to work with HTTP redirects in an embedded MSIE (via SWT).

Comment: @Chaquotay : how did you navigate around this problem ?